# How to replace prefix and postfix with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find some known prefix and postfix in text and replace them with the new prefix and postfix keeping the original text between them unchanged.

Example: I want to change `<h1>Title</h1>` to `<h2>Title</h2>`
Where "Title" can be any text which is unknown to me.

I'm using python and I have found how I can change the prefix and postfix:

```
s = "<h1>Title</h1>"
replaced = re.sub(r'(<h1>).*?(</h1>)', r'<h2>new text</h2>', s)
print(replaced)
```

This prints `<h2>new text</h2>`.
But, how can I get the original text printed between the tags?

Thank you!

Comment: Read the documentation: [7.2. re — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). This is called "grouping".

Comment: @anubhava: this prints `<h2>$1</h2>`

Comment: @anubhava that should be `\1`, not `$1`; see https://regex101.com/r/zJ0mU0/1

Comment: `replaced = re.sub(r'<h1>(.*?)</h1>', r'<h2>\1</h2>', s)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: \1 in this case ´<h1>´, so it prints ´<h2><h1></h2>´

Comment: @AleksejSpenst you still need the parentheses in the right place to capture the appropriate part - **look at the example** I've linked to

Comment: ´replaced = re.sub(r'<h1>(.*?)</h1>', r'<h2>\1</h2>', s)´ --> works fine, thanks a lot!! (yes, I didn't notice first that the parentheses changed, thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [anubhava has already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947216/how-to-replace-prefix-and-postfix-with-regex-in-python#comment53719470_32947216), you should use groups as this:

```
replaced = re.sub(r'(<h1>)(.*?)(</h1>)', r'<h2>\2</h2>', s)
```

This is your original regex, but you do not need to create groups for your prefix and postfix, only the content is enough:

```
replaced = re.sub(r'<h1>(.*?)</h1>', r'<h2>\1</h2>', s)
```